# spliting and customizing a string buffer in Java by JSON parser?

Tags: java, json, string, split, buffer

I have a string buffer (Payload) as follows :

```
"SQN":922,"Node_ID":"cc000000000000000000000000000002","Energy":"5.00","Power":"1.80","Sign":"6d226becaf5a5b..."
```

And now I want to customize it as follows :

```
String part_1 = "{9 spaces}922{3 spaces}5.00{3 spaces}1.80"
String part_2 = "6d226becaf5a5b..."
```

What is the best solution to do this ?

I tried this one as user  Martin P proposed :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.JSONArray.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject.*;
import org.json.JSONString;

String input = "{\"SQN\":922,\"Node_ID\":\"cc000000000000000000000000000002\",\"Energy\":\"5.00\",\"Power\":\"1.80\",\"Sign\":\"6d226becaf5a5b...\"}";

        JSONParser obj = ((Object) new JSONParser().parse(input)).getAsJsonObject();
        String sqnString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "SQN");
        String energyString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "Energy");
        String powerString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "Power");
        String signString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "Sign");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{whatever we need}").append(sqnString).append("{whatever we need}").append(energyString).append("{whatever we need}").append(powerString);
        String part_1 = sb.toString();
        String part_2 = signString;

        System.out.println(part_1);
        System.out.println(part_2);
```

However, `getAsJsonObject()` and `jsonObjectToString(obj, "SQN")` are undefined.

Comment: looks like you need a `JSON` parser

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thank you. Would you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: you take a json parser to parse you string and map it to a POJO. then you can access all the parts much easier

Comment: @XtremeBaumer since I am not familiar with JSON parser, Would you please do it as an answer? if it is possible and it is not difficult, Thanks

Comment: @sas see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java. Gson and Jackson are the most commonly used ones.

Comment: @Vladimir Vagaytsev just when i use "import org.json.simple.JSONArray" it can not be resolved do u know why ?

Comment: @sas you need to import necessary jar files to your classpath. Check another answers, use jackson or gson instead of `org.json` parser. The jar dependencies can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could parse it as Json.

I used Gson to do this. Here's the link to maven: [Gson maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

Be aware that I wrapped your string in curly brackets ( { } ) to parse it as json later on

Sample code:

```
String input = "{\"SQN\":922,\"Node_ID\":\"cc000000000000000000000000000002\",\"Energy\":\"5.00\",\"Power\":\"1.80\",\"Sign\":\"6d226becaf5a5b...\"}";

    JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(input).getAsJsonObject();
    String sqnString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "SQN");
    String energyString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "Energy");
    String powerString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "Power");
    String signString = jsonObjectToString(obj, "Sign");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{whatever you need}").append(sqnString).append("{whatever you need here}").append(energyString).append("{something else}").append(powerString);
    String part_1 = sb.toString();
    String part_2 = signString;

    System.out.println(part_1);
    System.out.println(part_2);
}

private static String jsonObjectToString(JsonObject obj, String name) {
    return obj.getAsJsonPrimitive(name).getAsString();
}
```

Result output:

> {whatever you need}922{whatever you need here}5.00{something else}1.80
>
> 6d226becaf5a5b...

Comment: Thanks. since i get an error for JsonObject, do you now related jar file to download ?

Comment: could you edit your original post and provide more details like code snippet and error message?

Comment: you're trying to use my code which I wrote using Gson library while importing org.json library. You can't do that. Either change your code to be compatible with org.json implementation or use Gson library instead.

Comment: How about jsonObjectToString ? It is not still recognized as a method. I imported import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

Comment: Look at my code snippet, it is a method that I provided myself